# scipy.optimize.minimize result outside boundaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, scipy

I have a set of 3 equations that I want to solve. The variables c[0], c[1], c[2] are cost functions in range -1 to 1. From what I found on the web scipy optimize is the best way to go. Everything in the equation except for c[0] to c[3] is constant and known.

> 0 = a + u * c[0]
>
> 0 = b + v * c[1] + w * c[2]
>
> 0 = d - n * c[1] + m * c[2]

I translate it into following optimization Problem with boundaries and constraints, so I need `SLSQP`

```
c=np.array([])
def fun(c):
    return abs(c[0])+abs(c[1])+abs(c[2])
    
x0 = [0.05,0.05,0.05]

bnds = [(-1.0,1.0),(-1.0,1.0),(-1.0,1.0)]

cons = ({'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda c: a+u*c[0]},
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda c: b+v*c[1]+w*c[2]},
    {'type': 'eq', 'fun': lambda c: d-n*c[1]+m*c[2]},
    )

res = minimize(fun, x0, method='SLSQP',
                        bounds=bnds,
                        constraints=cons)
```

I get:

```
status: 0
success: True
   njev: 3
   nfev: 15
    fun: 33.015905119807698
      x: array([  1.04805004e-02,   1.01768804e+01,  -2.28285442e+01])
message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
    jac: array([ 1.,  1., -1.,  0.])
    nit: 3
```

So my boundaries seem to be ignored. Translating the boundaries in inequalities delivered the same result

values for the calculation are

```
a = -3943.3960306568406
b = 172710.8224501527
d = -380842.9800419506
u = 376260.28
v = 112878.084
w = 57886.196
n = -3205737.5856
m = 1412423.1824
```

Comment: I'm sorry for the high values for the calculation but I didn't want to risk giving you wrong input

Comment: Try with Scipy version >= 0.15.0. (Also --- what is the value for `d`?)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In first Version I called d as c but I figured this would lead to missunderstandings with the variable, however I fixed it now. Originally I ran it on scipy 0.15.1 but now I updated it to scipy 0.16.1. The result is strange res says it was unsuccesful wit 101 Iteration steps but  the obtained values are ok.

Comment: You solved the Problem @pv. , the one I'm facing now is a different one^^ Post it as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: Your set of equations can be solved by hand - how do those values compare with the output? By inspection, c[0] is indeed correct.

Comment: @JonCuster the values are what I get by calculating by Hand. This piece of code is just the simple version of the actual optimization problem, which has a lot more variables

Comment: @Fips - Very good - sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with Scipy version >= 0.15.0.

The SLSQP routine has a known bug in previous versions in cases where jacobian of the constraint functions is not given.